# Change Bundle ID when Application state is Waiting for Upload

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I want to change `bundle ID` of my application from `iTunes Connect` to test in-app purchase with test account. Current state of my application is `Waiting for Upload`. I am trying to change `bundle ID` from App Information section from Manage Application, but it is not changing.

How can I change bundle ID for my application so that I can test in-app purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Please, do not test iAP purchase this way. Much better solution would be to create copy of your project and change bundle id there, in Xcode.

Comment: Current identifier attached to my application is App Store Profile. So how can I install application in device which is binded with App Store profile.